# What is the best way to perform an anti-transpose in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose

Lets say I have an array

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

0   1  2   3
4   5  6   7
8   9  10  11
12  13 14  15
```

But I want

```
15  11  7  3
14  10  6  2
13  9   5  1
12  8   4  0
```

which is a flip across the secondary diagonal, or a kind of anti-transpose.

How can I do this in numpy?

Comment: Have you attempted anything or are you simply getting your homework done by us...

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj self-answered question

Comment: @AnttiHaapala :O Oops. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One could do one of the following:

`rot90(a,2).T`

`rot90(flipud(a),1)`

`rot90(fliplr(a), -1)`

or as [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) suggested in the comments (thanks hpaulj)

`a[::-1,::-1].T`

Here are the speed rankings as ratios of the slowest method after anti-transposing 1000 random 10000x10000 arrays.

1. 63.5% - `a[::-1,::-1].T`
2. 85.6% - `rot90(a,2).T`
3. 97.8% - `rot90(flipud(a),1)`
4. 100% -`rot90(fliplr(a),-1)`

Comment: I'm hoping someone knows a secret numpy way of doing this.

Comment: `a[::-1,::-1].T`; this is a `view`, sharing the same data buffer, so it will be as fast as possible.  To test for view, try changing one element and see if it changes the original.  The double reverse slice is the same as `np.rot90(a,2)`.  Look at it's code.

Comment: @hpaulj so you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

`np.flip(a).T`

From the `np.flip` documentation & @hpaulj 's comment:

`flip(m) corresponds to m[::-1,::-1,...,::-1] with ::-1 at all positions.`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another to throw into the mix.

```
a.ravel('F')[::-1].reshape(a.shape)
```

Comment: Although I like this because of ravel, its also about 200x slower than `rot90(fliplr(a),-1)`. :/

Comment: No worries, I was just exploring other ways of doing it (-:

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this manner,

```
np=np[::-1] #reverse the array
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
```